# Complex MySQL Query - Checking for overlapping DATE intervals

Tags: php, mysql, date, intervals

I'm trying to write a function to move an scheduled task.  The schedule can not overlap with any other event. My user inputs are as follows:

- schedule_id (int)
- new_start_time (DATETIME)

My table structure is as follows:

```
Schedules
| schedule_id | start_time              | end_time              |   task_id
|     1       | 2015-12-21 02:00:00     | 2015-12-21 04:00:00   |      1 
|     2       | 2015-12-21 08:30:00     | 2015-12-21 09:30:00   |      1
|     3       | 2015-12-22 01:00:00     | 2015-12-22 02:00:00   |      2

Tasks
| task_id     | name                    | max_duration
|       1     | do things               |    2
|       2     | do stuff                |    1
```

A user has between `start_time` and `end_time` to start a "task".  The user can not begin the "task" until that window.  Once that user begins the task they have whatever the `max_duration` for that task ID is to complete it.  There is also a 15 minute window to set up for the next task.  That means a user who starts a task 1 second before the end of the window still has `max_duration` amount of time to complete the task.  Therefore the "actual window" that nothing can be scheduled in is `start_time` to (`end_time`+`max_duration`+`15`).  I would like to move an event (or insert a new one) but I must check for overlaps.  Essentially I must ensure:

- Does the `start_time` from user input run into any other schedule's `end_time`+`max_duration`+`15`?
- Does the `end_time`+`max_duration`+15 run into any other schedule's `start time`.  `end_time` is simply obtained by taking the new `start_time` and adding the original duration (`end_time` = (`orig_end_time`-`orig_start_time`)+`start_time`

For example, the above table is valid for schedule_id's 1 and 2 because a user can start any time between 2:00 and 4:00.  Assuming he starts right at the end, 3:59:59 the event will last at max until 5:59:59.  Even with the cleanup window of 15 minutes this still leads to 6:14:59 and since the next schedule starts at 8:30 this is ok.

I've been wrapping my head around this for hours.  I would like to do it in pure MySQL however I am considering using PHP if I really have to.  Even in PHP this problem seems difficult.  Sure I could grab every schedule with a start time a day or two earlier and an end time a day or two later then compare my interval but that seems very hacky.

Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanVincent - Ya, I have however the problem arises on the "left side".  I don't know what the proper "end" time of a possible overlapping schedule is prior to my query because I don't know the duration of that event (one can be an hour, one can be three).  I have to be able to do all the math and query at the same time

Comment: The rules sound good. Let's talk about process. Are you wanting a user to start work on your user interface and when the user starts, you want to do all the math and tell the user if it is OK to start or not?

Comment: in your schedule, how do you differentiate between the two records for task_id 1 ( is there an active flag ? )

Comment: @amdixon - I don't.  There could be `n` many schedules for a given task.  A task is just an action.  One person can `wash a car` between 2:00 - 4:00 PM (with 2 hours to wash it) and another person can `wash a car` between 8:30 and 9:30 (with 2 hours to do it).  They don't have to be unique.

Comment: then how do you differentiate between the different user task schedules

Comment: @amidixon - There is a `userid` column that was not shown because I felt it was not relevant since the premise of the question is "Does my newly inserted schedule conflict with anything else?"  I could care less if the Pope, Obama, or a bum is `washing the car`.  All I care is that `someone` wants to start `wash a car` between `X` and `Y` and we know that `wash a car` takes two hours