# Checking if new interval overlaps - MySQL (or PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, scheduling, intervals

I've been thinking on how I can simplify the problem presented here.  [Complex MySQL Query - Checking for overlapping DATE intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406020/complex-mysql-query-checking-for-overlapping-date-intervals)

At it's heart, minus all the fancy magic with DATES this is simply a problem of checking for overlapping intervals.  After all dates can be thought of as numbers and it may make the logic easier.  Imagine the following table:

```
Schedules
schedule_id     |     start     |       end 
1               |       1       |       3
2               |       4       |       7                
3               |       8       |       13
4               |      15       |       16
5               |      18       |       24
6               |      25       |       28
```

I'm trying to insert a new interval such that [a,b] do not overlap with any other interval.  The considerations:

- Yes, I can pull the whole table into an array and do an O(N) search on it.  That's boring.
- I prefer to do this in MySQL so I don't have to pull down what can be an arbitrarily large table every time.

See the following image.  This represents the bounds of what can and can not be inserted. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE59w.png

Comment: What interval do you want to insert?  If you want just any, then choose the maximum `end` value and add one for the start.  You can then make the `end` any larger value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I want to insert an arbitrary interval such that there are no conflicts with any other interval.  The intervals can be of arbitrary length.  According to the image I posted the small interval at the top will be  "valid" as it does not conflict where as on the bottom I tried to represent all the possible conflicts I could think of.  Basically "Does my new interval run into (or is contained in) anything existing?  Does anything run into (or is contained in) my new interval?"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Schedules WHERE start <= 17 AND end >= 16` would return all intervals with which your proposed insertion conflicts.

Comment: That's won't work in the blue case.  Sure we `SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE start <=14 and end >= 17` however the orange is contained within where the blue wants to go.  This also doesn't avoid an O(N) lookup.  I get all of these rows from the query but I stil have to do an O(N) search on them (does row1 overlap? does row2 overlap, does row3 overlap...)

Comment: In the blue case it would be `WHERE start <= 17 AND end >= 14`.  It does work, in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using folowing abbreviations:

- *[old]* := existing range
- *[new]* := inserting range
- *OS* := (old) existing_range.start
- *OE* := (old) existing_range.end
- *NS* := (new) inserting_range.start
- *NE* := (new) inserting_range.end

the condition for overlaping of two ranges (old and new) is: `(OS < NE) AND (OE > NS)`

While the solution might be not trivial, its not that difficult to get there:

There is no overlaping if the new range is completly before or after the existing range: `[new] <= [old] OR [old] <= [new]` and that means that:

```
(NE <= OS) OR (OE <= NS)
```

Negotiating this statement we get the condition for overlaping:

```
!( (NE <= OS) OR (OE <= NS) )
```

Now using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) we can write it as

```
!(NE <= OS) AND !(OE <= NS)
```

And this is equivalent to

```
(NE > OS) AND (OE > NS)
```

wich can be rewriten as

```
(OS < NE) AND (OE > NS)
```

Now we can find all overlaping ranges using

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Schedules o
WHERE o.start < :new_end
  AND o.end   > :new_start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can phrase an insert as:

```
insert into schedules(start, end)
    select s, e
    from (select $start s, $end as e) t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from schedules s2
                      where s.start <= t.end and s.end >= t.start
                     );
```

This will only insert the value if it doesn't overlap with an existing row in the table.